# Thread causing IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

This piece of code causes an IndexOutOfBoundsException
Can anyone please tell me why?
I can't undertstand why it is causing an IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
private static String TRACE_PATH = "..\\..\\TRACES";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(TRACE_PATH))
    {
        String[] traceEntries = Directory.GetFiles(TRACE_PATH);
        Thread[] traceReaders = new Thread[traceEntries.Length];


        for (int i = 0; i < traceEntries.Length; i++)
        {
            traceReaders[i] = new Thread(()=>readTrace(traceEntries[i]));
            traceReaders[i].Start();
        }

    }

    Console.Read();
}

private static void readTrace(String traceFile)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(traceFile))
    {
       //code to use the trace file...
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: traceReaders[i] = new Thread(()=>readTrace(traceEntries[i]));
                traceReaders[i].Start();

Answer (score 6):

Just declare a temp variable inside your loop. You are capturing the variable not the value.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < traceEntries.Length; i++)
 {
       var j = i;   
       traceReaders[j] = new Thread(()=>readTrace(traceEntries[j]));
       traceReaders[j].Start();
 }
```

Comment: It works. I know it's because of the lambda expression but can you please explain the logic behind it?

Comment: @user2936347 similar to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). Just note that this behaviour of foreach loop changed in c# 5.0

Comment: @user2936347 actually, you are passing `i` to lambda expr not its value. at the time some threads starts, for-loop may have been executed and the value of `i` is `traceEntries.Length`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to write it this way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < traceEntries.Length; i++)
{
    var traceEntry = traceEntries[i];
    traceReaders[i] = new Thread(() => readTrace(traceEntry));
    traceReaders[i].Start();
}
```

The explanation is that your variable `i` is send as parameter to a lambda expression. When the lamba expression is executed on the thread, your for loop will be already done, and thus `i` will be equal to the `traceEnties.Length`.

By declaring the `traceEntry` as local variable, you remove the dependency of the local variable `i` which is updated in the for loop.

The same thing happens in L.B.'s answer. It's a matter of taste how to deal with it I guess.