# For loop cause IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: c#, .net

I faced a curious situation today when I developing windows service.

I have a MonitorOutputFile inside which I implement FileSystemWatcher in the method MonitorOutputFile.

When I wrote the code as below

```
foreach (string filePath in filePathValue)
{new Thread(() => monitorController.MonitorOutputFile(filePath, pollRetryInterval, fileWaitTime)).Start();}
```

-->It works well in the OnStart();

However, when I use

```
for(int i=0;i<filePathValue.Length;i++)
{
new Thread(() => monitorController.MonitorOutputFile(filePathValue[i], pollRetryInterval, fileWaitTime)).Start();
}
```

-->This throw IndexOutOfBoundException in the OnStart() method.

I tot that is my problem, so I do a output

```
for(int i=0;i<filePathValue.Length;i++)
{
EventLog.WriteEntry(SourceName, filePathValue[i], EventLogEntryType.Information, 58987);
}
```

-->This able to output the correct output of the filePathValue[i].

Unlike [Thread causing IndexOutOfBoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927401/thread-causing-indexoutofbounds-exception)
which was expecting a return value, my windows service does not wait for any return value. Does this two having the similarity?

Can somebody tell me why is this happening? Hope that somebody able to share some light with me on this curious case.

Comment: I wish to mark all as answer and that does help me to understand more about lambda. Thanks all :) Cheers for Friday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda captures the last `i` value, which is `filePathValue.Length`. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filePathValue.Length; i++)
{
    int i1 = i;
    new Thread(
        () => monitorController.MonitorOutputFile(
             filePathValue[i1], pollRetryInterval, fileWaitTime)).Start();
}
```

Comment: That very much depends on the C# version, but it's the likely explanation.

Comment: @BartvanNierop No; In all version of c# this is the behavior.

Comment: @BartvanNierop: Behaviour was changed in C# 5 for the `foreach` variable, but not for the `for` counter.

Comment: @Douglas I did not know that. Based on the `foreach` behaviour, I assumed. Assumption is the mother of all ... :/ Thanks.

Comment: If you're interested in the rationale, read Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. You're capturing the loop counter in your anonymous method, so all the threads, once they execute, are likely to read the same (final) value of `i`. Instead, you should assign `i` to a variable declared within the loop body, ensuring that each thread reads its own copy.

```
for(int i=0;i<filePathValue.Length;i++)
{
    int iInner = i;
    new Thread(() => monitorController.MonitorOutputFile(filePathValue[iInner], pollRetryInterval, fileWaitTime)).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When variable i is send as parameter to a lambda expression. When the lamba expression is executed this in the thread, your for loop will be already done. so you can create a inner variable to hold the value. I think you can try the below code, it should be work

```
for(int i=0;i<filePathValue.Length;i++)
{
  var fileValue =filePathValue[i];
 new Thread(() => monitorController.MonitorOutputFile(fileValue, pollRetryInterval, fileWaitTime)).Start();
}
```